# How do I get rid of the NameError and TypeError

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, typeerror, nameerror

I keep getting an error of

```
NameError: name animal_type is not defined
```

or

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'animal_type' and 'name'
```

no matter if I change the line to

```
animal = Animal.Animal(animal_type, animal)
```

or

```
animal = Animal.Animal()
```

and it has this later:

```
#Add animal to list
def addAnimal(animal):
    atype = input("What type of animal would you like to create? ")
    theAnimal = atype
    theAnimal = Animal.Animal()
    theAnimal.set_animal_type(atype)
    aname = input("What is the animal's name? ")
    theName = aname
    theName = Animal.Animal()
    theName.set_name(aname)
    zookeeper.add_animal(theAnimal, theName)
```

To give some background, this program has 2 classes that it imports.

Here is one that I am calling:

```
import random

class Animal:

    #initialize attributes
    def __init__(self,animal_type, name, mood = None):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__name = name
        if mood:
            self.__mood = mood
        else:
            self.check_mood()

    # set methods
    def set_animal_type(self, animal_type):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `NameError` because in your second file (the one you are importing the `Animal` class into), you haven't defined your variables.

```
animal = Animal.Animal(animal_type, animal)
```

`animal_type` and/or `animal` have not been defined.

As for the `TypeError`, the problem with

```
animal = Animal.Animal()
```

is that you aren't passing any of the required variables. `animal_type` and `animal`.

For example:

```
import Animal # Animal.py

atype = 'Snake'
name = 'George'
a = Animal.Animal(atype, name)
```

Or simply

```
import Animal # Animal.py

a = Animal.Animal('Snake', 'George')
```

**Other Problems (after the edit):**

#### 1.)

You don't need to create a new class instance when you `set_name` or `set_animal_type`. (in `addAnimal`)

What you *should* be doing is this:

```
theAnimal = Animal.Animal(atype, aname)
```

#### 2.)

You need to have your `input`s *first*. Like so:

```
def addAnimal(animal):
    atype = input("What type of animal would you like to create? ")
    aname = input("What is the animal's name? ")
    theAnimal = Animal.Animal(atype, aname)
    theAnimal.set_animal_type(atype)
    theAnimal.set_name(aname)
    zookeeper.add_animal(theAnimal, aname)
```

#### 3.)

Your `addAnimal` function does not need any variables. They are not used.

```
def addAnimal(animal):
```

should be

```
def addAnimal():
```

Comment: I've made corrections to the code so you can see that I do define it later

Comment: where is the zookeeper.add_animal coming from?

Comment: Your post. In the `addAnimal` function. @Trevor